# RailsでBootstrapテンプレートを適用する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
デザインのためにAdminLTE テンプレートを使おうとしています。
https://almsaeedstudio.com/

最初はgemで入れようとしましたが、gemを入れて設定まで記述されている資料があまりありませんでしたし、gemを入れて設定までしてもうまく適用されませんでした。
それで、ライブラリをダウンロードして、プロジェクトのlibフォルダーの中に入れる方法が多く検索されて入れましたが、プロジェクト全体に適用できるようにapplication.cssファイルとapplication.jsファイルでの設定をどうすればいいのかわからなくて困っています。
gemでもライブラリを入れる方法でもいいので、application.html.erbファイルで全部読み込めるように詳しく教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 試してないんですが、githubに書いてある通りでは上手くいかないってことですか？ https://github.com/shine60vn/adminlte-rails

Comment: @itmammoth 返事ありがとうございました。上記のURLの場合、バージョンが古くて使えないという内容を見たことがありました。あと、一応内容を試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。